# Cambiar color y tamaño en la termial mediante Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas compañeros. El hecho es que quería saber si se puede modificar el tamaño y el color de fuente en una aplicación de consola que estoy haciendo. En python. Utilizando Windows 10 . Para hacerla un poco mas llamativa.

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante realizar preguntas en base a  [ask]  agrega lo que haz investigado o realizado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el módulo [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) es muy fácil de usar:

`from colorama import Fore
 print(Fore.RED + 'este texto se imprime en color rojo')`

Comment: amigo estoy intentando importar el modulo colorama y no me funciona. Uso la version 3.61 de python. Alguna idea?

Comment: Instalaste el modulo usando `pip install colorama`?

Comment: @limg21 [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) no  es un módulo de la biblioteca estándar, debes descargarlo e instalarlo: vete a la consola de Windows (cmd) y pones `py -3.6 -m pip install colorama` o `python -m pip install colorama`